# Android Recyclerview's Content ClickListener not working Properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**My Adapter Code For RecyclerView :**

```
package com.shubham.recyclerviewandroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<youtubeListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;
    List<String> liked_list;
    private youtubeRecyclerViewClickInterface youtubeRecyclerViewInterface;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> liked_list, List<youtubeListItem> listItems, Context context, youtubeRecyclerViewClickInterface youtubeRecyclerViewInterface) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.liked_list = liked_list;
        this.youtubeRecyclerViewInterface = youtubeRecyclerViewInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.youtube_videos_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final youtubeListItem item = listItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.youtubeHeading.setText(item.getHeading());
        holder.youtubePostedOn.setText(item.getPostedOn());
        Picasso.with(context).load("https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + item.getImageUrl() + "/default.jpg").into(holder.youtubeImageView);

        holder.youtubeShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.getImageUrl();
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Using"));
            }
        });

        holder.youtubeLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!liked_list.contains(item.getId())) {

                    liked_list.add(item.getId());
                    Log.e("LikedList", liked_list.toString());
                    holder.youtubeLike.setText("You Liked It");
                    holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://c69a7f6efbdd.ngrok.io/api/likeVideo", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("user_id", "1");
                            params.put("scheme_id", item.getId());
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                } else {
                    Log.e("LikedList", liked_list.toString());
                    holder.youtubeLike.setText("You Liked It");
                    holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }

            }
        });

        if (liked_list.contains(item.getId())) {
            Log.e("LikedList", liked_list.toString());
            holder.youtubeLike.setText("You Liked It");
            holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView youtubeHeading;
        public TextView youtubePostedOn;
        public TextView youtubeShare;
        public ImageView youtubeImageView;
        public TextView youtubeLike;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            youtubeHeading = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeHeading);
            youtubePostedOn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtubePostedOn);
            youtubeShare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeShare);
            youtubeImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.YoutubeVideoImage);
            youtubeLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeLike);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    youtubeRecyclerViewInterface.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When i clicked the liked Button in the RecyclerView , it sends volley api request to my server and the textview turns blue which is perfect for me but when i scroll my recyclerview other similar TextViews also turns blue . Why is it so ? i am not getting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

RecyclerView is named such, because it recycles inflated view for next item and just will be applied all changes that you've defined in OnBindViewHolder. So you must check both states of item that is liked or not.

so use the

```
if (liked_list.contains(item.getId())) {
        Log.e("LikedList", liked_list.toString());
        holder.youtubeLike.setText("You Liked It");
        holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }else{
         holder.youtubeLike.setText("You dont Liked It");
         holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_red_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
         holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

instead of

```
if (liked_list.contains(item.getId())) {
        Log.e("LikedList", liked_list.toString());
        holder.youtubeLike.setText("You Liked It");
        holder.youtubeLike.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.youtubeLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```